# Display lines of data with horizontal and vertical scrolling iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I wish to display a dynamic set of data (pulled live over a TCP connection) on the iPhone that is not too unlike lines from a terminal.

This means that the lines will be very long and really cannot be wrapped.

**What is the best way of accomplishing this?**

I want to use a `UITableView` because then memory issues would be less of a concern because the lines of text would be loaded/unloaded automatically each line of text would be a cell.

I have thought about this a bit and I came up with a possible solution, but I am not sure if it would actually work.

I could put a `UITableView` in a `UIScrollView` and only let the containing `UIScrollView` scroll horizontally.

Then I would adjust the frame of the `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`s so that they are much wider as calculated by the longest line of text.

I have read that you really don't want to nest a `UITableView` in a `UIScrollView` since `UITableView` is in fact a subclass of `UIScrollView`. Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, is there someway I can enable the horizontal scrolling and make the frame wider?

If either of those ideas would actually work, could you also tell me which properties I should change (`frame` or `contentSize` etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting a `UILabel` in a `UIScrollView` and just kept an array of all the lines and  made the `UILabel` the minimum necessary width and height.

I then set the number of lines of the `UILabel` to the number of elements in the array. This works because there is no textwrapping.

I think this should be fine performance wise, but we'll see.

You can see it in action in my app [Adminium for Bukkit/Minecraft](http://adminiumapp.com/):

[image: UILabel in a UIScrollview]